# Can I change the name of the mysql shell?

Tags: mysql, windows, path, mysql-shell

This isn't exactly an issue, but more of a check to make sure I'm not making a mistake.
I recently started with mysql, and I couldn't access the shell.

I looked through my path variables and found out mysql shell is actually called mysqlsh. i made a copy of the shell and called it mysql instead. but I'm waried it might cause an error if I do so.

Therfore, I wanted to ask a question to make sure that this isn't gonna bite in the ass later, it is okay to change the name of mysql, right?

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL product still includes the traditional command-line interface, [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html).

[MySQL Shell](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-shell-userguide.html) is a different client with different features (at least it's installed separately in MySQL 8.0, perhaps this will change in the future).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-shell-userguide.html:

> MySQL Shell is a component that you can install separately.

So it could cause confusion if you rename the executable `mysqlsh` to `mysql`. Then if you install both on the same computer, which one would it run? It would depend on which one it finds first as it searches your Bash PATH.

I would suggest you do not rename the executable. If you want it to run the MySQL Shell when you type `mysql` in the Bash shell, I would recommend defining an alias in your `.bashrc`.

```
alias mysql=mysqlsh
```

Comment: thanks you! i actually just made a copy of mysqlsh which i called mysql (with both of them at the same folder), but is probably better